# ASP WebForms routing - Get route url by physical file

Tags: asp.net, webforms, routes

I have set up 10+ *MapPageRoutes*, which works fine. Now I need to generate urls for menus. Method *Page.GetRouteUrl* seems not applicable, because I dont want to setup every link manually.

Is there any solution for get route url by physical file?

For example If I have MapPageRoute

```
routes.MapPageRoute("RouteOne", "Users", "~/UsersList.aspx");
```

and I need somehow get "Users" by "~/UsersList.aspx".

Answer (score 0):

Use `query string` for dynamic menu pages and then use `URL Rewrite Rule` for that query string so it will look like below.. according to below you will get different url for all dynamic menu pages

Original

```
http://www.yoururl.com/page?id=1
http://www.yoururl.com/page?id=2
```

After URL rewrite

```
http://www.yoururl.com/page/1
http://www.yoururl.com/page/2
```

for more reference URL Rewrite - http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: I cannot use this solution, because Im working on already completed web site, where menu contains links like /staticpages/Service_centers.aspx, /contact.aspx, /Category_card.aspx?Category=2 and so on

Comment: @DanielTreml Then it will be more easy.. you have to use only URL Rewrite rules only....

Comment: Sorry I should be more specific, but I dont want make it more complicated...  I use this to translate url to page supported languages so if I have route url "Users" I have also other 4 translaton of it. And I need for english speaking user generate links in english and for german speaking links in german. Thats why I use routing, because I think this cannot be solved by rewriting.

Comment: @DanielTreml I think you don't know abt asp.net coding much.. so I can't give you complete coding, I can just help you by providing proper concept... other things you have to do by your self..